# Is it possible to use a non-local proxy to connect to the Internet?

Tags: networking, internet, proxy

I have a friend who lives 5 miles from me - so we can't have a wired connection to each other. Is it possible to turn his computer into a proxy and let me connect to the Internet through him?

I'm trying to do this is because he has a really fast Internet that he doesn't use much in contrast to me - a gamer, streamer, I do use Internet a lot.

So I believe if I have his computer as a proxy, it'd be faster to connect between me and him and then connect to the Internet. Correct me if I'm wrong but I believe it should work.

Answer (score 4):

Typically, a proxy server is located between you and the internet, like in the diagram below:

[image]

In this case, the connection speed between your devices and your proxy server will be limited only by the local network speed (usually ethernet or wireless). **The main bottleneck here will be the proxy's processor/RAM performance.**

This setup is not mandatory *per se*: the proxy can be located elsewhere. However, in this case, your data has to go through your internet connection first. It will flow from your computer to your modem/router, then to your phone line and then to your ISP (assuming you use ADSL).

[image]

In this other case, the connection between your devices and the proxy will be limited by your ISP. As you can see in the image, **you are still connecting to the internet using your ISP, just like before setting up the proxy**.

Actually, if you set a device on your friend's house as a proxy, your internet experience might even become *slower*, as you won't be able to take advantage of the multi-routed nature of the internet, as each connection will, *obligatorily*, pass through your friend's proxy (even if there was a much shorter and faster way elsewhere).

**The bottleneck here will be your friend's connection**. Your internet usage will now be subject to *his* latency, lags, pings, etc. Even more so in the occasions where your friend might be using his own connection.

That will be even more pronnounced if you set *all* the data from *all* your devices to use this proxy (not to comment on the inconvenience of doing so on every device you might own).

The **only** scenario where you'll benefit from it is if the connection from you to your friend is really fast, but the connection from you to more distant destinations is really slow, *and* the connection from your friend to these distant destinations is really fast. Your ISP will only see the local end of the data stream, and it will be served fast by the proxy.

However, I'd favor more a VPN than a simple web proxy: a VPN would reroute all data, while "proxy" usually refers to a web proxy, that deals only with web pages and other browser data. With a web proxy you need built-in support for every software you plan using (browsers have it, but online games not). When a VPN is active, it usually applies to the OS as a whole.

You can set up an OpenVPN server at your friend and connect there using a VPN client. Or you can hire a cheap server on your country just for it, I pay less than USD 15 / year for one, the specs required are really low.

Comment: Well I understand what you are telling me, but the reason i think my speed can and will improve is because:
- I mostly use international internet services (Youtube, games, ...)
- My ISP has good national speed (between me and my friend) but has bad worldwide speed (my main usage)
- In the other hand, my friend has really good Internet and its better than mine in general, also all he does with it is reading news and facebooking.
So I think this will be a good idea, please correct me if I'm wrong, I can provide specific numbers if you somehow need them :)
Thank you

Comment: @Danny Well, in this very specific case, it might help. I've expanded the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)
The main problem i was having was not knowing where to start, now i know it's VPN i can work on from now, thanks once more !